# Connecting to LDAPS from Java in multitenancy

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, jsse

I'm looking for a way to connect to an [LDAP Server over SSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAPS) from Java in a scenario where you can have multiple users, each one with its own truststore (Basically each user is an application deployed on a Java application server).
I think it should be possible to connect to LDAPs using a Custom SSL Connection Factory. Something like this:

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(DirContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(DirContext.PROVIDER_URL, url );
env.put(DirContext.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(DirContext.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, principal);
env.put(DirContext.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, credentials);
env.put("java.naming.ldap.factory.socket", "MySSLSocketFactory");
```

However, if the property "java.naming.ldap.factory.socket" is set at JVM level, I believe each applicaton will overwrite the current SSL Factory. On the other hand, I'd need to have a distinct SSLSocketFactory for each user. Is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: You mean that all three applications are run in the same JVM?

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: That property is set in `env`. That’s not at the JVM level. It is per connection.

Comment: That's right: I don't see where the problem lies

Comment: There is no problem. JNDI was designed for this. 27 years ago.